# How can I force all derived classes to implement an abstract method or property?

Tags: c#, .net, rules

An abstract function must be implemented by all concrete classes.

Sometimes you want to force all derivative classes to implement the abstract function, even derivatives of concrete classes.

```
class Base { protected abstract Base Clone(); }
class Concrete : Base { protected override Base Clone(){...}; }
class Custom : Concrete {}
```

I would like the compiler to tell the programmer that the class `Custom` needs to implement `Clone()`. Is there way?

Comment: As long as some concrete class in the inheritance tree has implemented the abstract method, why would you care if a child of that concrete class relies on its parent's implementation?

Comment: I'm late to the party but I have the same problem. I'd love to have a `private abstract` qualifier which forces every derived class to implement the function but prevents the classe's code to implicitly fall back to the implementation of a parent class. `Clone()` is a good example. My case is more like `ToString()`. Something generic but distinct per class.

Comment: Actually this must occur more often (or I'm missing something).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible for the compiler to enforce this.   You might look at writing your own analysis plugin to [Gendarme](http://mono-project.com/Gendarme) or [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) to enforce such requirements.

Comment: How would the plugin distinguish between the case where you want to force the requirement on all derivatives or just the immediate ones?

Comment: An Attribute would be the most straightforward approach -
[MustImplement] or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess you don't really need ALL derived classes to implement the abstract method, but it definitely sounds like you have a bit of a code smell in your design.

If you don't have any functionality in the Concrete.Clone() method, then you can make your 'Concrete' class abstract as well (just be sure to change the name ;-).  Leave out any reference of the Clone() method.

```
abstract class Base { protected abstract void Clone(); }
abstract class Concrete : Base { }
class Custom : Concrete { protected override void Clone() { /* do something */ } }
```

If you have some basic functionality in the Concrete.Clone() method, but need detailed information from a higher level, then break it out into it's own abstract method or property forcing a higher level implementation to supply this information.

```
abstract class Base { protected abstract void Clone(); }

abstract class ConcreteForDatabases : Base 
{ 
    protected abstract string CopyInsertStatemement {get;}

    protected override void Clone()
    {
        // setup db connection & command objects
        string sql = CopyInsertStatemement;
        // process the statement
        // clean up db objects
    }
}

class CustomBusinessThingy : ConcreteForDatabases 
{
    protected override string CopyInsertStatemement {get{return "insert myTable(...) select ... from myTable where ...";}}
}
```

Comment: I fixed my example Clone methods to return Base. When you implement object cloning using virtual Clone methods, you need *all* derivative classes to implement the abstract method.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make `Concrete` an abstract class to enforce that.

Comment: The goal is to have a base class that is easy to extend. You do not have control over how people are going to extend your class. You may not even be around. First prize is to document the requirement in code that the compiler can enforce.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this at run-time using reflection and throw an exception to disrupt execution, wrecking havoc for "impolite" users of your library. Performance-wise that is not very wise, even though you could store a static *HashSet<System.Type>* in the base abstract class with all verified types.

I think your best bet is to provide clear documentation that tells any user of your code that it is deemed necessary to override the Clone() method.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the following NUnit test that uses reflection to check the implementation. Hopefully you can adapt as needed.

I suspect it won't handle overloaded methods well, but it's sufficient for what I want.

(Comments welcome)

```
/// <summary>
/// Use on a (possibly abstract) method or property to indicate that all subclasses must provide their own implementation.
/// 
/// This is stronger than just abstract, as when you have
/// 
/// A { public abstract void Method()}
/// B: A { public override void Method(){} }
/// C: B {} 
/// 
/// C will be marked as an error
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AllSubclassesMustOverrideAttribute : Attribute
{

}

[TestFixture]
public class AllSubclassesMustOverrideAttributeTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SubclassesOverride()
    {
        var failingClasses = new List<string>();

        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    foreach (var methodInfo in type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.HasAttributeOfType<AllSubclassesMustOverrideAttribute>()))
                    {
                        foreach (var subClass in type.ThisTypeAndSubClasses())
                        {
                            var subclassMethod = subClass.GetMethod(methodInfo.Name);

                            if (subclassMethod.DeclaringType != subClass)
                            {
                                failingClasses.Add(string.Format("Class {0} has no override for method {1}", subClass.FullName, methodInfo.Name));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.HasAttributeOfType<AllSubclassesMustOverrideAttribute>()))
                    {
                        foreach (var subClass in type.ThisTypeAndSubClasses())
                        {
                            var subclassProperty = subClass.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);

                            if (subclassProperty.DeclaringType != subClass)
                            {
                                failingClasses.Add(string.Format("Class {0} has no override for property {1}", subClass.FullName, propertyInfo.Name));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
                // This will happen sometimes when running the tests in the NUnit runner. Ignore.
            }
        }

        if (failingClasses.Any())
        {
            Assert.Fail(string.Join("\n", failingClasses));
        }
    }
}
```

It uses the following extension methods

```
    public static bool HasAttributeOfType<T>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        return provider.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false).Length > 0;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> ThisTypeAndSubClasses(this Type startingType)
    {
        var types = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (startingType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    {
                        types.Add(type);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
                // Some assembly types are unable to be loaded when running as nunit tests.
                // Move on to the next assembly
            }
        }
        return types;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

remove implementation  in concreate  class or use base class